# Роутинг (или алиас) в Yii1

Tags: php, yii, маршрутизация

У меня есть классы на front-end типа HotelsController и другие, к ним доступ идет через модуль поиска как search/hotels/.

```
function getUrlRules()
{
return array(
        $this->id.'/<controller:\w+>/<action:(SupportBlock)>/<countryId:\d+>' => $this->id.'/<controller>/<action>',
        $this->id.'/<controller:\w+>/<action:(SupportBlock)>/<countryId:\d+>/<cityId:\d+>' => $this->id.'/<controller>/<action>'
    );

}
```

Вопрос вот в чем - если я изменю название класса с HotelsController на FrontendHotelsController, как мне сделать так чтобы ПУТЬ (search/hotels/) остался таким же, а не менялся на search/frontendhotels/ ? Я пробовал добавлять frontend в роутинг но там это не работает, выводит ошибку что "Невозможно обработать запрос "search/hotels""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это было решено следующим способом:

1. В конфигурации у модуля поиска (searches) был проставлен controllerMap вот так:

   ```
   'modules' => array(
       'search' => array('controllerMap' => array('hotels' => array('class' => 'FrontHotelsController')))),
   ```

И соответственно название файла И контроллера было изменено на FrontHotelsController ([источник](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1467))